# Django 'str' object is not callable on form submission

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

Trying to perform an ajax request for a form submission, but keep getting the above error.

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^register-me/$', 'registerMe', name='registerMe'),
)
```

My views.py

```
def registerMe(request):
inviteeEmail = 'ryan@nenvy.com'
inviteeName = 'ryan'
```

Exception Data

```
    Traceback:
File "/Users/psdstaff/Projects/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /register-me/
Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable
Request information:
GET:
name = u'asdf'
email = u'asdf'
```

Comment: possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668040/django-str-object-is-not-callable?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your URLs you need to specify the full path to the view function:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^register-me/$', 'app.views.registerMe', name='registerMe'),
)
```